# Google Finance style control for Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, charts

I'd like to make a timeline where you can view an overview and zoom in on certain portions of the timeline for more detail.  Basically, I want what Google Finance has.

Is there anything out there that can provide exactly that, or at least get me close?  I'm using Swing and SwingX for my GUI components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [JIDE Charts](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/charts.htm) as a starting point.  I have used JIDE Charts and really like the package.  It's very modular and easy to use.  We actually created and maintain a charting package which implements features like you describe.  We created a custom solution, which was very appropriate for our application.  I only discovered JIDE Charts recently, but my first impression was actually that we probably could have built almost our whole package using that library as a foundation.

Another option would be [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/).  I have not used JFreeChart personally, but another person on my team at work is using it and getting decent results.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using JFreeChart now.  It works ok, but it's going to be a lot of work to close the gap to what I need.